# Whats wrong with this query trigger?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I would like to create a trigger that would log the following changes in the table "osoba" (changes in column "login")

I have this table "osoba":

```
CREATE TABLE Osoba (
  id_osoba SERIAL NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  login VARCHAR,
  jmeno VARCHAR,
  prijmeni VARCHAR,
  heslo_hash VARCHAR,
)
```

and this log table

```
    CREATE TABLE osoba_zmeny(
    operace         char(1)   NOT NULL,
    cas_otisk       timestamp NOT NULL,
    id_osoba        integer   NOT NULL,
    login           text      NOT NULL,
);
```

with the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION osoba_zmeny() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $osoba_zmeny$
    BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO osoba_zmeny SELECT 'D', now(), id_osoba, OLD.login;
            RETURN OLD;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            INSERT INTO osoba_zmeny SELECT 'U', now(), id_osoba, NEW.login;
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO osoba_zmeny SELECT 'I', now(), id_osoba, NEW.login;
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$osoba_zmeny$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS osoba_zmeny on osoba;
CREATE TRIGGER osoba_zmeny
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON osoba
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE osoba_zmeny();
```

CREATE TRIGGER - Query returned successfully, but if I want to insert a record into the table "Osoba", it return:

```
INSERT INTO public.osoba(
    id_osoba, login, jmeno, prijmeni, heslo_hash)
    VALUES (13, 'test_login', 'test_jmeno', 'test_prijmeni', 'test_heslo_hash');

    ERROR:  column "id_osoba" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO osoba_zmeny SELECT 'I', now(), id_osoba, NEW.log...
                                                   ^
HINT:  There is a column named "id_osoba" in table "osoba_zmeny", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
QUERY:  INSERT INTO osoba_zmeny SELECT 'I', now(), id_osoba, NEW.login
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function osoba_zmeny() line 10 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42703
```

do you know somebody what I did wrong? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using a `select` for the `INSERT`? And as the error message indicates, the `id_osoba` can't be referenced without a table. You need to take that from the `NEW` or `OLD` record, depending on the type of the trigger, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO osoba_zmeny SELECT 'D', now(), id_osoba, OLD.login;
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO osoba_zmeny values ('D', now(), old.id_osoba, OLD.login);
```

Same for the second select